# Dell T7600 Second Set of PCIe x16 slots not enabled

Tags: dell

According to Dell, the T7600 has an optional second set of PCIe x16 slots above the CPUs that are available only when the second CPU is installed.

I have a second CPU installed (and I know its working), and yet any card I install in these particular PCIe slots are not recognised - move the card to one of the slots below the CPU and the card becomes recognised.

Is there anything I need to do specifically to enable these PCIe slots above and beyond installing a second CPU?

Comment: How do you know the second CPU is working?

Comment: @MichaelHampton both the full expected number of cores and full expected amount of memory (which populates all the banks, half of which are only available to the second CPU) show up in all tests.